# SSIS - Move and open zip file / load xml file to the BD

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, ssis

first of all you're amazing.

About my problem, what i have to do, is:

I have a folder in the sftp with multiple files (zip). 
What i need do do is, load those files from the sftp, one by one to a stagging folder, open them, inside they are 3 files, 2 pdf and one xml.
I need to upload the xml to the bd.
After that, based in one field of the xml (ExternalID) i need to move the file in some folder, that depends of the ExternalID, before i move the files, i need to zip all 3 files and name the zip with the ExternalID.

Anyone did something similar? Or some advises to do this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: You have three steps and do one step at a time 1) Use SFTP to download files 2) UnZip files 3) Upload XML to BD.

Comment: You know any tutorial or similar?

Comment: I closed your other questions as they're duplicative of this one. Read the help section on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You've got solid starts so refine this question with the information you've gained and where you are unable to get past the roadblocks. Searching individually for SFTP & SSIS, unzip & ssis and Load XML & SSIS should net you a plethora of examples to work from. String them all together and you have a working solution. Or at least a good, detailed problem for us to help with.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS doesn't support SFTP natively.

WinSCP (free of charge) could be handy.
Here is its link: [SFTP Task for SSIS/SSDT](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis)

Comment: With cozyrock file transfer task editor i can do that no? Im doing it for excel/csv files

Comment: Yes, COZYROC supports it: https://www.cozyroc.com/products But it is a commercial product.(not free).

Comment: I have a license. You have any tip or advice how to do all of that?

Comment: It is a standard project for SSIS. IMHO, stackoverflow.com is not a right avenue to get it done.